# Babylonian numbers representation

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am new to java and have received the following assignment to complete over the next 2 weeks. Any pointers as to how to begin would be appreciated:

> Write a Java class whose instances represent Babylonian numbers. Your class should provide at least the following methods:

1. A constructor that takes a number expressed in Babylonian form as input (as a `String` e.g. `"34,45,2"` or `"1,23,4,59,55"`, etc.)
2. A method to return the value of the current Babylonian number as an integer;
3. A method to convert a Babylonian number to String form;
4. A method to add two Babylonian numbers together to produce a new Babylonian number;
5. A method to subtract a passed Babylonian number from the current Babylonian number to produce a new Babylonian number;

> If there are restrictions on the magnitude of the numbers that can be represented by your class, say what those restrictions are.

Comment: Start here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below you will find a set of methods, which might help you:

```
/**
 * A representation of a Babylonina number.
 * <p>
 * TODO some examples/explanations of what Babyloninan numbers
 */
class Babylonian
{
  /**
   * Constructs a Babylonina number from a string.
   */
  public Babylonian(String number)
  {
  }

  /**
   * Returns the value of this Babyloninan number as an {@code int}.
   *
   * @return the value of this Babylonian number (as an int)
   */
  public int getBabylonian()
  {
  }

  /**
   * Returns the value of this Babyloninan number as a {@code String}.
   *
   * @return the value of this Babylonian number (as a String)
   */
  public String toString()
  {
  }

  /**
   * Adds the Babylonian number {@code x} to this number.
   *
   * @param x the Babylonian number to add
   */
  public void add(Babylonian x)
  {
  }

  /**
   * Substracts the Babylonian number {@code x} to this number.
   *
   * @param x the Babylonian number to substract
   */
  public void subtract(Babylonian x)
  {
  }
}
```